# how to print html code

Tags: theming

Could you please help me, i'm trying to print a block of html code.

Im using a template file wid.tpl.php i need to pass some variables:

```
$htmlget = theme('wid',array('id'=> $id,'temp'=> $temp,'game'=> $game));
```

and this is my code on that file:

```
<?php
$list = get_defined_vars();
$idcompetition=$list['idcompetition'];
$temporada=$list['temporada'];
$idgame=$list['idgame'];

print "<style>
.Opta h2{background-color: #ff191e !important;}
</style>
<link rel='stylesheet' href='https://secure.widget.cloud.opta.net/v3/css/v3.football.opta-widgets.css'>
<script src='https://secure.widget.cloud.opta.net/v3/v3.opta-widgets.js'></script>
<script>
    var opta_settings = {
    subscription_id: 'bccfa17c076140fd251fc5edc10c4dc6',
    language: 'es_CO',
    timezone: 'America/Mexico_City'
    };
</script>
 <div id='container-opta-all-widget'> 
        <opta-widget competition=". $idcompetition." season=". $temporada." match=". $idgame."></opta-widget>
</div>";
?>
```

but i need run that javascripts files `v3.opta-widgets.js` and that between `<script>` tags to add somethings to `container-opta-all-widget` tag

how can i do that

Answer (score 0):

You should preprocess the template itself in template.php, and call `drupal_add_js` to add inline JS like that when you need it.

https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21common.inc/function/drupal_add_js/7.x

You can do the same with `drupal_add_css` too.

HTML code does not need to go within `<?php ?>` tags. Just write it as normal and inject your variables like `<?php print $variable; ?>`.